# Fragment not showing listview items

Tags: android, mysql, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

Hi everyone I have this Fragment Create Method

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    user_id = sp.getString("user_id", "anon");

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends_list, null, false);

    listview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
    fadapter = new FriendsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.single_friend);
    listview.setAdapter(fadapter);
    listview.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    fadapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            listview.setSelection(fadapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
```

I see in my log that my dataprovider is creating the listitems
This class is inside my fragment.java

```
 class GetFriends extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));

        Log.w("params", params.toString());

        Log.d("request!", "starting");
        // getting product details by making HTTP request
        jsonArray = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                EVENTS_URL, "POST", params);

        Log.w("jsonArray", jsonArray.toString());
        if (jsonArray != null) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    Log.w("jsonArray", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());

                    //CREATE ITEM FOR LISTVIEW
                    fadapter.add(new FriendsProvider(
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("username")));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

But my fragmentlist is not showing anything.

Fragmentlistview:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.myup2.up2.FriendsFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/friends_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff" />
```

SingleFriend - List item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/singleFriend"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:background="@drawable/own_event_bubble"
    android:text="hello worldvfvdfvdfvdfv"
    />
```

Adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_friend,parent,false);
    }
    friends_item = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.singleFriend);

    FriendsProvider provider = getItem(position);

    friends_item.setText(provider.username );

    return convertView;
}
```

Maybe I'am thinking to complicated with the adapter and the provider.
But it was working from other parts of the app.

But maybe I have to refresh the UI of the fragment or anything like this?

**Edit 1:**

```
public class FriendsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FriendsProvider>{

private List<FriendsProvider> friends_list = new ArrayList<FriendsProvider>();
private TextView friends_item;
Context ctx;

public FriendsAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    ctx = context;
}

@Override
public void add(FriendsProvider object) {
    friends_list.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return friends_list.size();
}

@Override
public FriendsProvider getItem(int position) {
    return friends_list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_friend,parent,false);
    }
    friends_item = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.singleFriend);

    FriendsProvider provider = getItem(position);

    friends_item.setText(provider.username );

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problems is that you never call to `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`when you finished to add items in your adapter.

Please try adding the onPostExecute() in your **AsyncTask**

```
 protected void onPostExecute() {
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

Comment: @Konter I need that you copy and paste all code of your adapter pless. If not is very complicated help you.

Comment: the fragment does not go into the onPostExecute(). I will copy the adapter into the first post

Answer (score 0):

getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { was the answer

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (jsonArray != null) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                Log.w("jsonArray", jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());

                                //CREATE ITEM FOR LISTVIEW
                                fadapter.add(new FriendsProvider(
                                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"),
                                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("username")));
                                fadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe with the *FrameLayout* you are using, according to [android developers - FrameLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) *FrameLayout* may block some views from showing up, I didn't know how to fix it with *FrameLayout* but it worked when I replaced it by *LinearLayout*..

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.